# Why do I see passed props in HTML output in a React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I have a simple Text component created with Styled components:

```
const Text = styled.p`
  color: ${({color, theme}) => color ? theme.colors[color] : 'inherit'};
`;
```

It works, however for some reason I can see the `color` prop passed in an HTML output in console.

```
<p color="gray700" class="sc-ifAKCX GLYnD">2 active deals</p>
```

Weird is that if I rename the prop from `color` to `variant`, it doesn't appear in the console:

```
<p class="sc-ifAKCX GLYnD">2 active deals</p>
```

What does this depend on?

Comment: How are you rendering the <Text> ?

Comment: @MatthewBarbara, `<Text color="gray700">...</Text>` inside a stateless functional component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have been trying to figure out this for over an hour but finally I found the reason.

The `color` prop is being passed down to your HTML because `color` is an attribute of the `<font>` HTML tag  and thus this is the expected behavior.

Therefore I would avoid using `color` as prop for styled-components/React to avoid passing down unnecessary HTML attributes

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_font_color.asp

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! I have quite a few of `direction` or `wrap` props I happen to use here and there. Would have to think of a better naming for those too.

Comment: They should be according to your answer because they are visible iin the HTML output same as the color prop 